# Despair!—The cry of arrogance

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> A magical land bearing a shielded man,
> whom a Y succeeds. And then a XY
> who leaps with joy at the sight of Hope-
> a hope never then seen before.
> I am a king, altogether.
> Despair!

#### Who am I?

I am *not just* a word,
*but also* a **CHARACTER**.

Comment: I think this is easily the best of your riddles yet! Though I am a sucker for cryptic wordplay...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is...

> **Ozymandias**

Explanation:

> From [Shelley's poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias): *"My name is Ozymandias, king of kings: Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!"* So:
>  The magical land (with its shielded 'wizard') is **OZ**,
>  It's succeeded by a **Y**,
>  XY is male, so **MAN**,
>  And Bartolomeu **DIAS** is the Portuguese navigator and the first European who discovered the Cape of Good *Hope*.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> An [Earl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl)

A magical land
bearing a shielded man,

> Land's might be referring to England, Scotland etc

whom a Y succeeds.
Then a XY
who leaps with joy
at the sight of hope-

> An earl has the title Earl of [X] etc

A hope never seen before.
I am a king, altogether.
Despair!

> Earl's are basically noblemen with highest positions and can be called as Kings.

Comment: Cool guess! Unfortunately, not the answer.